# Page_validators in grid for client side validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, grid

Hi i am using `Page_Validators` to validate some text boxes before bind into grid.

My actual requirement is that I have two grids on same page. If i took `Page_Validators` from the DOM it contains total validators in pages. How can I identity this validator for particular grid?

Anyone please help me stuck with this.

Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general sense, you can figure out the parent of an object by using jQuery's `.parents()` function:

HTML--

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS--

```
var $the_parent = $('.child').parents('.parent');
```

This will traverse through the `.child` element's ancestors until it finds the `.parent` element.

You can find documentation for `.parents()` here: http://api.jquery.com/parents

Without more information about your problem I can't help much. Some posted code on jsfiddle or a link to your live site would be helpful.

Comment: My control is like this 
HTML
<Grid ID="Grid1">
<form>
<control to validate>......
</form>

</Grid>

my design is like this. How would i find?

Comment: @YogeshWaran `$(<control to validate>).parents('[id^="Grid"]');` --> this will select the ancestor element of your `<control to validate>` element based on finding a parent element whose ID starts with "Grid".